# React native ScrollView resets positon on setState

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have a `ScrollView` with buttons on it. I populate `ScrollView` dynamicaly. After I press on the buttons inside the `ScrollView`, I'm changing the state of the current selected index and the posiotion of `ScrollView` is resetting.

```jsx
<ScrollView
  ref={ref => {
    this._scrollview = ref;
  }}
  style={styles.scrollview}
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  snapToInterval={64}
  snapToAlignment="start"
  decelerationRate="fast"
  contentContainerStyle={{ paddingRight: 8, paddingLeft: 8 }}>
    {this._channels.map((item, index) =>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onLayout={event => {
          const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          this._channelsPositions[index] = layout.x;
        }}
        key={item.userId}
        onPress={() => this._changeIndex(index)}>

        <Image
          source={{ uri: videos[index][0].channelThumbnails.high.url }}
          style={[styles.channelLogo, index == this.state.currentIndex ? { borderWidth: 2 } : {}]}
        />
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )}
</ScrollView>

_changeIndex = (newIndex: number) => {
  const { currentIndex } = this.state;
  if (newIndex == currentIndex) return;

  this.setState({
    currentIndex: newIndex
  });

  const newX = 16 + 48 * newIndex
  this._scrollview.scrollTo({
    x: 16 + 48 * newIndex,
    y: 0,
    animated: true
  })
}
```

And after I press the button I want `ScrollView` to move to `x` position of this button inside the `ScrollView`.
Demo: https://streamable.com/gu1edy

**Update:** After i replace scrollview for Flatlist in header i think i understand why is it happening. But i still don't know how to fix it. So the behavior is same, i am getting scroll reset every time i press on the button/cell/item of scrollview/flatlist. 
How looks my flatlist with nested flatlist in header

```
\ |CHANNEL ICON 0|CHANNEL ICON 1|CHANNEL ICON 2| ... \     header with flatlist         

\ FIRST ITEM IN FLATLIST WHICH CONTAINS VIDEO OF CHANNEL\  cell 0
\ SECOND ITEM IN FLATLIST WHICH CONTAINS VIDEO OF CHANNEL\ cell 1
```

...

So after i klick on channel icon all main flatlist populates with new data so if i understand right the header rerendering and repopulates with new data too. So is there a possibility to update header with flatlist that way my scroll in header stays on it's position without resetting?

Comment: Have you tried Flatlist?

Comment: Not yet, but if i  can i make pagination like  `snapToInterval={64}` and auto scroll to index after i press on item then i think i will migrate to Flatlist. But i am not sure can i put FlatList inside FlatList's header....

Comment: Yes you can use flatlist inside flatlist as it gives to render the items you want to. So it will be better to give it a try. Because pagination feature is itself provided by flatlist so.

Comment: Ye i replace with flatlist, same problem. Looks like i am doing overall something wrong..

Comment: I do have the same exact problem. First I'm using Flatlist, and then using Scrollview and it has same problem. This is hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have been fixed it by moving Scrollview from my partial Functional Component to main Function Component screen.

For example you have two functions :

- component RenderListProducts
- screen/page Product

So the solution is move Scrollview of Flatlist inside RenderListProducts and paste it to indside of screen/page Product.

Try it. If you still have this problem, please put comment below.